# how to clear JavaScript variable value after few minutes / seconds / times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set a value in JavaScript local variable which is given below:

```
document.getElementById("class").value = getSavedValue("class");    // set the value to this input
document.getElementById("group").value = getSavedValue("group");   // set the value to this input
document.getElementById("section").value = getSavedValue("section");   // set the value to this input
document.getElementById("session").value = getSavedValue("session");   // set the value to this input
document.getElementById("shift").value = getSavedValue("shift");   // set the value to this input
document.getElementById("version").value = getSavedValue("version");   // set the value to this input
/* Here you can add more inputs to set value. if it's saved */

//Save the value function - save it to localStorage as (ID, VALUE)
function saveValue(e){
    var id = e.id;  // get the sender's id to save it .
    var val = e.value; // get the value.
    localStorage.setItem(id, val);// Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override .
}

//get the saved value function - return the value of "v" from localStorage.
function getSavedValue  (v){
    if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
        return "";// You can change this to your defualt value.
    }
    return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
```

i want to when its value is saved then a certain amount of time it only that (specific) variable will be unset / clear automatically.

Thank you

Comment: Save the time that the variable was set in another localstorage variable. When you come back to the page, check the timestamp and compare it to the current time.

Comment: How many values do you intend to store and how accurate do you need the timeouts to be?

Comment: Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/

Answer (score 1):

Set a timeout each time the variable is stored. And, depending on what you want, maybe sessionStorage is a better option.

```
function saveValue(e){
  var id = e.id;
  var val = e.value;
  localStorage.setItem(id, val);

  clearTimeout(localStorage.getItem(id + '_timeout'));

  var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() { localStorage.removeItem(id); }, 1000);

  localStorage.setItem(id + '_timeout', timeoutId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility to do this, as I think, is setInterval function:

```
// Repeat function alert every 2 sec
let timerId = setInterval(() => alert('tick'), 2000);

// Stop repeating after 5 sec
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); alert('stop'); }, 5000);`
```

Comment: `setInterval` is not the correct mechanism for this use case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When setting a value, cancel any existing deletion callback for that key, then configure a new callback using `setTimeout` to delete the entry, then set the item.

But remember, the timekeeping accuracy of `setTimeout` varies.

```js
const timeoutIds = {}
function set({key, value, lifetime}) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutIds[key])
    timeoutIds[key] = setTimeout(() => localStorage.removeItem(key), lifetime)
    localStorage.setItem(key, value)
}

function get(key){
    return localStorage.getItem(key)
}
```

Another solution might be to write a timestamp along with the value, and then check for the validity of the value only when it is next read from storage.

```js
function set({key, value}, lifetime){
    const expires = Date.now() + lifetime
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({value, expires}))
}

function get(key){
    const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))
    if (value === null) return null
    if(item.expires <= Date.now()) {
        localStorage.removeItem(item.key)
        return null
    }
    return item.value
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you might be able to get something working with a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) and [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).